# Programatically activate and deactivate network interfaces using nmcli

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I wrote a script that deactivates all the interfaces available using nmcli commands such as:

```
for iface in `(nmcli -f GENERAL dev list 2>/dev/null || nmcli -f GENERAL dev show) | grep 'GENERAL.DEVICE' | awk '{print $2}'`
do
    nmcli dev disconnect iface $iface
done
```

I would now like to reactivate these interfaces; there is no `nmcli dev connect iface …` command, and I'm stuck. In particular, my problem is to reactivate the Ethernet interface.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
nmcli -p con up id "interface name" iface eth0
```

You can also use `uuid` instead of `id`.

`-p` is just for human readable output and can be ignored.

`iface eth0` can also be omitted.

Take a look [here](http://www.linux-commands-examples.com/nmcli) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is: how to get the `uuid`(s) that are specific to Ethernet interfaces?

Comment: `nmcli con list` gives the uuid, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, that should do the job if I `grep` on the word `ethernet`... Thanks!